# UnInstall Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

I want to uninstall Visual Studio 2010 because the installation is corrupt, but impossible to do so.
When I try to uninstall with the control panel, it got stuck at the beginning (I found on the web that I am not the only one).
So I tried to use [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=1), but it got stuck too!!

I am completely out of ideas and I am in a hurry, can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

[image]

Comment: did you try to repair the product instead of uninstalling it ?

Comment: or may be use other uninstallers like Revo Uninstaller?

Comment: try to re-install it again and then perform uninstall.

Comment: You can restore the windows before the time you install Vs 2010.

Comment: I cannot re-install it, like the uninstall it is stuck at the initialisation

Comment: same problem, google cant help :(

Answer (score 17):

Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility by Microsoft, this can be downloaded from here:

[Download link](http://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall)

This handy little tool did not only runs successfully, but it completely removes and uninstalls Visual Studio 2010 and all it's installed modules.

The Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility can be ran in 3 different modes:

Default (VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe)

Uninstalls all top level products of 2010 release and its supporting components. This mode does not remove Visual Studio components shared with previous product releases (e.g. Visual Studio 2008) or system level updates such as Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.

Full (VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full)

Removes Visual Studio 2010 and supporting products, including components shared with previous versions of Visual Studio. Note: may break features of previous versions of Visual Studio installed on the machine. This option does not remove Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 from the machine.

Complete (VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx)

Removes entire set of Visual Studio 2010 and supporting products, including Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 and components shared with previous versions of Visual Studio. Note: may break features of previous versions of Visual Studio or other products taking dependency on Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.

[More information can be found here:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/08/23/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility.aspx?PageIndex=2)

Comment: As I said in my post, I already tried it, and it is stuck (see the screen shot)

Comment: can you try to re-install VS 2010.

Comment: :I tried but the modify/repair launch the same init method (it seems) and it is the one that block

Comment: Start the machine in safe mode and then try. Please refer following links to get more help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/recurring-werfaultexe-takes-up-99-plus-of-my-cpu/652a026b-bed2-4698-b49a-13931f751763

Comment: :I did not think of checking the event viewer, I'll try that tonight!

Comment: Looks like your links are broken and my google-fu isn't helping me find the new home of the Uninstall Utility.

Comment: Looks like download link of vs2010 uninstall utility is broken. [This](http://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall) is the new link. @Tinister

Comment: @Romil You are welcome. Could you please update the link in the answer if you find my link appropriate?

Answer (score 8):

I once had such a problem and struggled a lot before being able to uninstall it. I wrote the following PowerShell script for doing so:

```
# Be careful with that axe, Eugene.

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | 
select @{Name='Guid';Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, @{Name='Disp';Expression={($_.GetValue("DisplayName"))}} | 
where-object {$_.Disp -ilike "*Studio*"} | 
where-object {$_.Guid -like '{*'} | 
% {"rem " + $_.Disp; '$Env:WinDir\system32\msiexec.exe /x "' + $_.Guid + '" /passive'; ''} > uninstallVS.bat
```

This generates a .bat file that you can run to uninstall the thing.

**No need to say that this is an absolute last resort / desperate measure. Don't use it if your life is not threatened.**

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today and discovered the the removal tool does NOT remove SP1, you should remove SP1 through Add/Remove programs in the control panel and then use the tool.

Comment: Yes Eric, format is the easiest and fastest solution for this Microsoft crapware.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if it is allowed in your control panel/Uninstall programs.

Click the Visual Studio version you want to remove.At the top of installed programs, you will Organize and Change links.Click Change.This should lead you uninstall the visual studio you selected.
Another option is to run

```
wmic product where "name like 'microsoft visual studio%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

In your command promp.Be sure to run command prompt as administrator.You should be very careful for this.